# Should i send socketmessages directly from client or go my through restapi-server?

Tags: rest, sockets, design-patterns, architecture

I have my frontend mobile-application and my backend. I am building a chat-application and I wonder how I should structure my socketmessages. For example is a user sends a message, I call my backend to create the message in the database, but right now my backend will also send a socketmessage to my socketserver which will broadcast it to the user I sent the message to. I wonder, is it better to send the message to the socketserver directly from the frontend, so the frontend basically does two things when sending a message, calling my backend to create the message in db, and then also calling the socket to broadcast the message? Same goes for "isTyping"-state. For me it makes sense to not go via https and just directly send it to the socket, but what if I would like to also send a notification when user is typing, then it would make more sense to call the backend and let it send the info to the socketserver.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), Modularity, and a few more principles I can think of - I believe your front-end should call a back-end, and not the socket directly. In my humble opinion, this approach leads to several good things in the design:

1. You'll have **cohesive** components with very clear responsibility for each - front-end shows the data, back-end serves the data to the front-end (or processing the data from the front-end). This architecture enables better testability & deployability.
2. You won't have **coupling** between presentation layer and data layer - in future you might decide that you want to replace the `socketmessage` mechanism with something else, with this approach - the back-end is your abstraction and you'll only need to do the adaptations there, without touching/re-deploying the front-end (what might cause bugs, especially after years when there are new developers in the team who are not familiar with the old code).

Having said that, in software architecture usually there is no "perfect" solution, it's all about trade-offs. I believe that given the scenario you presented, there are more advantages to the back-end approach.

In addition, if you're interested, there is a book I recommend regarding these stuff [Fundamentals of Software Architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fundamentals-of-software/9781492043447/) .

Comment: So you would argue its better to create endpoints on my backend for this like /isTyping? So even if it will be slower, the benefits it gives in design and structure is more important in your opinion? And basically the socketserver I have set up will never recieve any messages from outside the backend?

Comment: @Odinhufnagl this was more like general guidelines, but as I stated in the last paragraph -  there is no "always" and there are trade-offs. If for funcrionality like 'isTyping' there is significant importance for low latency, it's possible to ignore the guidelines :)

Comment: Yeah and I understand that it always differ. It just feels like with events like isTyping, new chat-message and isActive for a user, is such standard events for a chatapplication it feels like it should exist a standardized way of what to do, but I may be wrong